# Animate button from right to left

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have a swipe gesture on `UITableViewCell`, when it happens a button appears
I'd like to add animation to that button, animation should reveal the button from left to right.

What do I need to add to the following code, so the button will appear/fade in from left to right?

```
// set the original frame
button.frame = CGRectMake(30, 50, 100, 100);

// animate
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 70, 100, 100);
}];
```

Comment: Have you added the button to the view? and is it visible?

Comment: you added this code and the animation is not working? I don't get you

Comment: @incmiko this is not working as i want it to i'm looking for a swipe effect from left to right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
UIButton* animatingButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 100, 100)];
[animatingButton setTitle:@"text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self addSubview:animatingButton];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    animatingButton.frame = CGRectMake(220, 200, 100, 100);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // your animation finished
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically add a UIButton you have to first create the object and then add it in a UIView. After that you can do animations with it.